# How to build Qt - OpenGL with MinGW 64 bit?

Tags: qt, opengl, mingw, mingw-w64

Practically each Qt installer has an instance with `OpenGL` in title of file and without it. As I understand `OpenGL` presence in filename means its support. So if I need to use OpenGL in my application I need to install Qt-OpenGL. But thereis no Qt installer for Windows 64 bit with MinGW and OpenGL. I couldn't also find it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/external-binary-packages/Qt-Builds/). So how can I make Qt-OpenGL MinGW for Windows 64 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the OpenGL version of Qt to use OpenGL in your application. The OpenGL in the Qt version only tells you what backend the Qt graphics use internally.

See this [wiki page for details](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL).

[This page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit), although a tad outdated, should still tell you how to properly build Qt on Windows with MinGW-w64. There's some dependencies you'll need to compile as well. And lots of time.

Answer (score 2):

As it mentioned in [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#aea23489ce3aa9b6406ebb28e0cda430):

> In Windows, two options are available:
>
> - Use the ANGLE-library [code.google.com] to translate OpenGL calls into DirectX (default)
> - Use the native OpenGL driver for your graphics card

Basically version with opengl in the name is just means that the second variant was used.

Though still there's no x64 version for usage with MinGW on Qt website to download (by the way 32-bit version would work fine on windows 64 bit actually) so you'll have to build it manually.

I guess sticking to [guide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) provided is mostly enough.  You'll have to install all of the required dependencies and then it's mostly typical `configure && make` sequence with some options available. If you have some specific problems with building I guess you may address them here or ask another question.